# Obama's grammar mistake?

Tags: expressions

[Source](http://washingtonexaminer.com/obama-praises-new-fbi-director-james-comey-at-swearing-in-ceremony/article/2537978)

> It's just about impossible to find a matter of justice he hasn't tackled and someone who **isn't more** uniquely qualified to lead the FBI.

Isn't this sentence strange?
I think this is supposed to be "*...impossible to find someone who is more uniquely qualified to lead the FBI.*"

But this is coming from Obama...so it's strange.

Comment: He did overnegate, but what he [actually said](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/video/james-comey-fbi-director-swearing-fbi-director-require-20704932) was "It’s just about impossible to find a matter of justice he has not tackled, and it’s hard to imagine somebody who is not more uniquely qualified to lead a bureau that covers all of it -- traditional threats like violent and organized crime to the constantly changing threats like terrorism and cyber-security." (21:53)  For whatever reason, newspapers like to rewrite people's quotes without making it obvious that they've done so.

Comment: I don't still understand..."I can't find someone who is not more uniquely qualified" literally means "You are the least qualified." So what is it a compliment?

Comment: You've caught an interesting nuance, but I'd guess that 90% of the people reading the quote – understanding what the president was getting at – would simply gloss over it, and catch the intended meaning almost automatically.

Comment: Yes. I'd think so. But grammatically, you can say Obama made a mistake?

Comment: Indeed Obama did.

Comment: @kih: Some would say that Obama has made a lot of mistakes, but that's a different forum ;^)

Comment: But why is nobody making a fuss in the media world? That'S a big wonder...

Comment: Maybe. Kudos to you for catching it—that's a sign you're grasping English well—but it's probably too common and small a mistake to send media people running to their pens and keyboards. It's not on par with his costly [unclear antecedent](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/compost/post/you-didnt-build-what-grammar-vs-the-president/2012/07/26/gJQADfmuBX_blog.html) and nowhere near the level of [some solecisms committed by his predecessor](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/bush.htm). As J.R. remarks in his political comment, political comments are for another forum. The grammar's answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [issue of “I could/couldn't care less”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/706/which-is-correct-could-care-less-or-couldnt-care-less) and is an example, as [snailboat](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailboat) [observes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/obamas-grammar-mistake#comment-19962), of [overnegation](https://www.google.com/search?q=overnegate).

It is, as you guess and [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) [confirms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/obamas-grammar-mistake#comment-19974), a grammatical mistake, but also, as [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r) [says](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/obamas-grammar-mistake#comment-19969), one that native speakers are not likely to notice, let alone misinterpret.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is clearly a mistake. It sticks out like a sore thumb to me. I think that Obama forgets the beginning of his sentences before he gets to the end of them. His advisors and the media are remiss in not correcting him, especially as he himself allegedly puts such great store by education.